# Copy values from one Oracle associative array to another

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have two pl/sql associative arrays array1 and array2

```
TYPE T_ARRAY1_REC IS RECORD(COL1 NUMBER,COL2 NUMBER,COL3 NUMBER,COL4 varchar2(1));    
TYPE T_ARRAY1 IS TABLE OF T_ARRAY1_REC INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
array1 T_ARRAY1;

TYPE T_ARRAY2_REC IS RECORD(COL1 NUMBER,COL2 NUMBER,COL3 NUMBER);    
TYPE T_ARRAY2 IS TABLE OF T_ARRAY2_REC INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
array2 T_ARRAY2;
```

How can I copy the value of col3 of array2 into col3 of array1? col1 and col2 are the common columns in both arrays

**Data for array 1**

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1     4         P
2     5         T
3     6         P
```

**Data for array 2**

```
col1 col2 col3 
1     4   56
2     5   67
3     6   89
```

After copying data in array1 should look like this

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 
1     4   56   P
2     5   67   T
3     6   89   P
```

Comment: Do they have the same number of elements and does the index match ?

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that the associative arrays may not be in the same order and can be sparse (so you cannot use a `FOR` loop) then you can loop through the arrays using a `WHILE` loop and `FIRST` and `NEXT` on the associative array:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE T_ARRAY1_REC IS RECORD(COL1 NUMBER,COL2 NUMBER,COL3 NUMBER,COL4 varchar2(1));    
  TYPE T_ARRAY1 IS TABLE OF T_ARRAY1_REC INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  array1 T_ARRAY1;

  TYPE T_ARRAY2_REC IS RECORD(COL1 NUMBER,COL2 NUMBER,COL3 NUMBER);    
  TYPE T_ARRAY2 IS TABLE OF T_ARRAY2_REC INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  array2 T_ARRAY2;

  i PLS_INTEGER;
  j PLS_INTEGER;
  
  FUNCTION findArray1Index(i_col1 NUMBER, i_col2 NUMBER)
    RETURN PLS_INTEGER
  IS
    i PLS_INTEGER := array1.FIRST;
  BEGIN
    WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
      IF array1(i).col1 = i_col1 AND array1(i).col2 = i_col2 THEN
        RETURN i;
      END IF;
      i := array1.NEXT(i);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NULL;
  END;
BEGIN
  array1(1).col1 := 1;
  array1(1).col2 := 4;
  array1(1).col4 := 'P';
  
  array1(2).col1 := 2;
  array1(2).col2 := 5;
  array1(2).col4 := 'T';

  array1(7).col1 := 3;
  array1(7).col2 := 6;
  array1(7).col4 := 'p';
  
  array2(1).col1 := 1;
  array2(1).col2 := 4;
  array2(1).col3 := 56;

  array2(7).col1 := 2;
  array2(7).col2 := 5;
  array2(7).col3 := 67;

  array2(4).col1 := 3;
  array2(4).col2 := 6;
  array2(4).col3 := 89;

  i := array2.FIRST;
  WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
    j := findArray1Index(array2(i).col1, array2(i).col2);
    IF j IS NOT NULL THEN
      array1(j).col3 := array2(i).col3;
    END IF;
    i := array2.NEXT(i);
  END LOOP;

  i := array1.FIRST;
  WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
      array1(i).col1 || ', ' ||
      array1(i).col2 || ', ' ||
      array1(i).col3 || ', ' ||
      array1(i).col4
    );
    i := array1.NEXT(i);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f1bb7d5b27fd1946a8af24a43b715a59)*